# Haskell. How to calculate the difference between two lists of string?

Tags: haskell, compare, difference

I have a question that can be described as this situation.

There are three different categories of books: Medical book, Art book and History book.
Each book has three level: Elementary, Intermediate, Advanced.

These books will be put on bookshelves.
The problem is to compare the difference about two different bookshelves.

I have abstracted this question as two lists of string.

For example:

---

Medical book -> M

Art book -> A

History book -> H

Elementary -> 1

Intermediate -> 2

Advanced -> 3

---

Now, the bookshelves can be defined as ["A1","H2","M3"].
Question:

  How many books are same? (Same category same level)
  How many books have the same category but wrong level?(not include the same book)
  How many books have the same level but wrong category?(not include the same book)

By the way, the same books are not put on the same bookshelf, which means every element in the list is unique and regardless of the order of the book.

Example

```
["A1","H2","M3"] ["A1","H3","A2"] -> (1 same book, 1 same category book,  2 same level books)  -> (1,1,2)
["H3","M2","A2"] ["H2","M1","H1"] -> (0 same book, 2 same category books, 1 same level book)   -> (0,2,1)
["A1","H1","M1"] ["A2","H2","M2"] -> (0 same book, 3 same catefory books, 0 same level book)   -> (0,3,0)
```

When I count the same category book with different level or same level book with different category, sometimes I got more than 3 ...

Comment: I do not get why for instance the first example has only one *same category* book?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have some code? If it doesn't compile, what's the error? If it does, what's the input/output pair for which it doesn't work? This question shows no effort to solve the problem, which makes it off-topic as it stands.

Comment: For the first example, because A1 was already counted as the same book(same category and same level), there are only H2 and H3 that has the same category but different level.

Comment: @ user2407038 when I tried to count the book with the same category but wrong level and the book with the same level but wrong category, sometimes, the same category or the same level will count more than once. Like, ["A1","H3","M3"] and ["A1","H3","M1"], the correct answer is (1,2,1), but I got (1,2,2), the level '3' are counted twice...

Answer (score 1):

The functions you want are in the [`Data.List` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#g:20), so import that. You will also need the `on` function from [`Data.Function`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html).

Rather than having the books represented as a two-element list like "H1", you should make them pairs: `('H', 1)`. It makes life much easier, and you don't have to worry about invalid titles.

The last bit of your question says that you never have two copies of a book on a shelf. That means that each shelf is a set of books. The `Data.List` module includes some set functions. So for instance the books that are the same in both lists is given by `intersect`, and the books on one shelf but not another are given by `(\\)`. You can also use the `By` variants of these functions, such as `intersectBy`. Each of these takes a function to use instead of `(==)`. If you represent a book by a pair as I suggested above then you can construct these functions like this:

```
zs = intersectBy ((==) `on` fst) xs ys
```